# Getting the line number in the ParserVisitor?

Tags: antlr, parse-tree

I'm trying to get line numbers for more specific error messages in my ParserVisitor (visits the parse tree generated by antlr). However, all I have in this class is the context `ctx`, and I can do things like `ctx.getText()` but not `getLine()`. Is there a way to do this?

Can `ctx.getPayload()` be used here? If so, how?

Edit: I'm using ANTLR 4 to create java files.

Trying to access the line number in a visitor in a method such as this:

```
@Override 
public Type visitStatAssign(@NotNull BasicParser.StatAssignContext ctx) {
...
// some semantic error detected
int lineNo = ...
System.err.("Semantic error at line " + lineNo); 
}
```

Edit 2:
My lexer and parser rules are fairly standard, for example in the lexer:

```
INT : 'int' ;
CHAR : 'char' ;
BOOL : 'bool' ;
STRING : 'string' ;
```

...is in the parser rule baseType:

```
baseType : INT | CHAR | BOOL | STRING ;
```

Comment: Can you post some code. Which version of ANTLR are you using?

Comment: Are you using tree grammar? Can you post it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by tree grammar? Sorry this is my first time posting!

Comment: You have to write a part for lexical analysis which converts your input into stream of tokens. This is defined by lexical rules. And tree grammar which converts your tokens into semantic tree. This is defined with parser rules. lexical rules + Parser rules = grammar rules.

Comment: Surely the tree grammar is irrelevant here? The parser visitor just goes over the tree generated by it. Wouldn't the line number in the parsed program be independent of these?

Answer (score 51):

You can get the first token in the rule with `ctx.start` or `ctx.getStart()`. Then use `getLine()` on the token to get the line number (and `getCharPositionInLine()` to get the column).

Comment: Thanks. I am using the Javascript target runtime, and ctx.start sure has the line value.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `ctx.getSourceInterval()` to get the range of tokens consumed by the rule. You can use [`TokenStream.get(int index)`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/TokenStream.html) to get the token associated with the source interval, and then get the position information from the token.

```
Interval sourceInterval = ctx.getSourceInterval();
Token firstToken = commonTokenStream.get(sourceInterval.a);
int line = firstToken.getLine();
```

Comment: there is no commonTokenStream when I try this

Comment: @johnktejik, `commonTokenStream` is available in `Antlr-v3`, you may using Antlr-v4

Answer (score 7):

If you have a ParserRuleContext Object, you can get the line number directly as suggested by @njlarsson:

```
ParserRuleContext ctx; 
int line = ctx.getStart().getLine();
```

However, if you have just a RuleContext Object, you need to Type Cast it to ParserRuleContext first:

```
RuleContext rctx;
ParserRuleContext ctx = (ParserRuleContext) rctx; 
int line = ctx.getStart().getLine();
```

Note: >> I'm using ANTLR4 >> In the code snippets above, `ctx` and `rctx` are not initialized for brevity. You need to initialize them with appropriate values e.g. `ParserRuleContext ctx = parser.compilationUnit();`